# iPhone/iOS: Best practices to shorten launch time of an app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I found it took 4-5 seconds on an iPhone4/iOS6.0 device, and I want to know what is the system doing in that time, are there any best practices to short the launch time of an app?

many thanks.

**EDIT:**
I log it and it took about 1.5s in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithoptions`:
,and it is like 3.5-4s(I used a clock to get a preciser time) from I tap the app icon to its launch screen disappear.That is to say, about 2-2.5s to launch the app before calling `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithoptions`

Comment: It's unlikely the system is taking 4-5 seconds — how much do you have happening in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching...`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply watch Session 225 *Up and Running: Making a Great Impression with Every Launch* from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), it will take you through the process of profiling your app launch and give tips on most often made mistakes, it's great.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very very good WWDC 2012 video with a long sequence devoted to *exactly* this topic: Session 235 (Responsiveness). I strongly recommend that you watch it. It gives you lots of hints and tricks for speeding up launch (don't link to too many libraries, etc.), tells you how to measure and how to read your measurements in Instruments, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The system isn't what's causing your app to take 4-5 seconds to launch. It's probably your code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, or the `init`, `viewDidLoad`, or other setup methods of your root view controller.

Profile your app on a real device with the 'Time Profiler' Instrument. *Only* launch your app, don't press any buttons on the UI once it's launched. We only want to see what's going on during launch.

I would suggest checking the 'Separate by Thread,' 'Invert Call Tree,' 'Hide System Libraries,' and 'Show Obj-C Only' options under 'Call Tree' on the lower left side of the window.

Once you've checked your chosen options, go down the list of method calls. Start with the ones taking the most time (for obvious reasons). You can double click on symbol names to get more detailed information on where time was spent. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.

Ultimately, we sped up launch time significantly by preloading the video in viewDidAppear. By the time the user taps the play button to launch the movie, enough content has loaded so that it can begin playback almost immediately.

e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://static.example.com/movie.mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    vc.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [vc.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.moviePlayerViewController = vc;
}
```

Full details in this blog post: http://blog.tetherpad.com/blog/2013/3/22/improving-tutorial-movie-load-times-on-ios-for-fun-and-profit

Comment: maybe you could load your video in background in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, which is earlier that your view controller's `viewDidAppear`, so that it won't block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the launch time mainly cost in function,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

If you do a bunch of stuff which blocks process, it will take long for launch.

So you can optimise your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` by moving out some unnecessary code which you can do later. Or you can make your code non-block, for example, you should use asynchronous network requests in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` instead of synchronous ones.